# Custom Sitecore Membership Provider does not contain Anonymous user

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore, sitecore7

In my development environment my custom domain wired up to a custom membership provider has an anonymous user `myDomain\Anonymous` however when I deployed to QC it does not contain the anonymous user (other users work fine).

For some background, I need the anonymous user to lock down pages with the deny read.

The domains configuration for both instances are the same, see below:

```
<domain name="sitecore" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
<domain name="extranet" />
<domain name="default" isDefault="true" />
<domain name="myDomain" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
```

Any ideas?  I'm running Sitecore 7 Update 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that you haven't set the switchingprovider correctly. So if you on one environment have: storeFullNames=true and the other environment have storeFullNames=false. This means that in one instance you have created "myDomain\Anonymous" and in the other instance you are trying to look after "Anonymous".

The property indicates whether domains should be included in the name.

Anyway, why don't you just set ensureAnonymousUser="true", then it will create the user for you?

Comment: This didn't work for us, we ended up restoring the QC core database from a Dev core database backup.  Doesn't seem like the right way, but it worked for now.  Anyway thank you.